# Problems with Apache Mod_Proxy and Microsoft's ReportViewer's Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd

Tags: apache-2.2, windows, sql-server-2008, reverse-proxy, ssrs

I've configured an Apache httpd server (v2.2) as a reverse proxy (with SSL) to a Microsoft IIS website running an ASP.NET application with SQL Server Report Services.

The proxy mostly works but Report Viewer reports aren't being proxied, all I get is a square window in Chrome and in IE I get the following error:

**This page contains both secure and nonsecure items. Do you want to display the non secure items?**

*I click yes then I get the following:*

**Unable to locate control: ReportFrame_ctl0_plchldrMainContent_1_ReportViewer1.**